# Laravel belongsToMany relationship return third column

Tags: php, laravel-4, eloquent

I'm trying to save part of a form data to a pivot table. This works fine while saving, but I'm not able to retried a third column (active boolean) while getting the relationship.

```
class _Event extends Eloquent {
    protected $table = 'events';

    public function groups()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Group', 'events_groups', 'event_id', 'group_id');
    }
}

class Group extends Eloquent {
    public function events()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('_Event', 'events_groups', 'group_id', 'event_id')->where('events_groups.active', 1);
    }
}
```

Running a `dd` of `(_Event::with('groups')->find($event_id));` gets me :

```
array(11) {
    ["id"] "1"
    ["groups"] array(2) {
        [0] array(4) {
            ["id"] "3"
            ["admin"] "0"
            ["pivot"] array(2) {
                ["event_id"] "1"
                ["group_id"] "3"
            }
        }
        [1] array(4) {
            ["id"] "4"
            ["admin"] "0"
            ["pivot"] array(2) {
                ["event_id"] "1"
                ["group_id"] "4"
            }
         }
    }
}
```

My DB is setup like this (unrelated columns removed) :

```
events : id
groups : id - admin
events_groups : id - event_id - group_id - active
```

How can I also retrieve the `active` column?`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want the `withPivot()` method.

From [the documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#working-with-pivot-tables):

> By default, only the keys will be present on the pivot object. If your pivot table contains extra attributes, you must specify them when defining the relationship:
>
> ```
> return $this->belongsToMany('Role')->withPivot('foo', 'bar');
> ```
>
> Now the foo and bar attributes will be accessible on our pivot object for the Role model.